# How can I grade a quiz?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have data in a spreadsheet like so:

```
Correct     Bob    Alice
   True    True    False
   True    True     True
  False   False    False
   True   False    False
            XXX      YYY
```

As you can see Bob got three questions correct, while Alice got two.

What formula can I put in locations XXX and YYY to have the spreadsheet compute this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your example begins in cell A1, put this in cell B6 to replace XXX:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(if(B2:B5=$A2:$A5,1,0)))
```